# How to know if my comment was removed/flagged?

Tags: support, comments

I've commented to another user's comment but now I can't see it there. There are no notifications about removal and (**this is an important part** - I have reasons to take into consideration that I might have forgotten to actually post it) I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'd like to know if the comment's been removed.

If it's been removed, I'd definitely want to know why. How do I do that?

If it's not been removed, I'd suspect that there **might** be a bug with the app for Android. How do I report that?

The post I'm referring to is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934853/how-to-bind-to-a-property-in-view-but-not-in-viewmodel/31935034#31935034) and it's the first comment to it's question that I commented on, as I wasn't really sure whether the commenter actually read the title or just went for tags.

Comment: Why did you link to the answer if you're talking about a comment on the question? It would be better to link directly to the post you are talking about.

Comment: @ChrisF Because (a) I can't link to the comment itself and (b) I don't want to draw visitors to the question itself. (I've heard that some people chase the badges for popular questions by asking questions about them and linking back. I don't do that and I'm therefore restrictive with that.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: your comment was flagged by a member of the community, then deleted by a moderator. Comments are ephemeral, and that particular comment was nothing more than a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Matt It was a rhetorical question the aim of which was to point out to the commenter that **his** point wasn't useful as he clearly hasn't read the question (or at the very least gravely failed to understand it). However, I admit he also might have missed the sarcasm, which makes it my fault. I'll make sure to re-comment. Thanks. However, I still don't see how to get to know if a comment's been removed (other than asking here).

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I know what the point of your rhetorical question was, but it wasn't as helpful or constructive as it could have been. To answer your broader question; there's no way to know whether a comment has been deleted/ removed by a moderator.

Comment: @Matt As I said before - I stand corrected and I'll try to remember to dial down my sarcasm a notch. Me being tired of ignorant users "beating around the bush" is no excuse for assuming that the next person appearing to do so, in fact, actually does that. Everybody deserves the benefit of doubt and I made a mistake by depriving said user of that right. Thanks for pointing it out so politely.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to know if the comment's been removed.

You don't get any notification or alert when a comment is deleted. Comments are not meant to be of any lasting value so their removal can be silent and instant. Moderator [Matt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) explained that a user raised a flag and a moderator [deleted your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302237/how-to-know-if-my-comment-was-removed-flagged#comment232387_302237)

> If it's been removed, I'd definitely want to know why. How do I do that?

You can raise it on meta. A moderator has to check the history of a post / user to verify deleted comments. They have an option to undelete but I would personally go *meh* on that.

Do know that for comments flagged as rude / offensive it only [takes a couple of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196436/158100) of ordinary users. No moderator will be involved in that process.

If you're absolutely sure the comment is OK (not considered offensive, too chatty or overly broad) and the reason you posted is not resolved you might consider re-posting it instead. If you're in doubt about the comment drop in a chatroom to have some extra eyes on it.

> If it's not been removed, I'd suspect that there might be a bug with the app for Android. How do I report that?

Bugs for the official Stack Exchange Mobile apps go on Meta Stack Exchange, where each has it own tag: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app